# Redirect UIAlertView Button Push Notifications

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, uialertview

I have read many posts on this matter, but none of them really helps me out. It seems quite easy to do, but somehow I can't figure it out.

What am I trying to do here?
Well, I send a push notifications to my app. Everything works fine.
I can handle it when it is in the background, inactive or even when the app is not running.
But one other state - app in foreground - gives me a headache.

I have this code snippet which I'm using. All fine.
When the app is running in the foreground, the user gets the UIAlertview.
But how do I add an action to the view button?
This particular action I mean: when someone taps the view button he/she gets redirected to the url which has been passed through the push notification.

Just like I have used before in the code snippet (this part to be precise):

```
NSString *notifUrl = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"url"];
NSLog(@"Received Push Url: %@", notifUrl);
```

I hope this makes sense and someone can help me out. I'm lost at this one ... This is the entire code snippet which is relevant at this subject.

```
-(void)Redirect:(NSString*)url{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
}     

/**
     * Remote Notification Received while application was open.
     */
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    #if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR

        NSLog(@"remote notification: %@",[userInfo description]);
        NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];

        NSString *alert = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"alert"];
        NSLog(@"Received Push Alert: %@", alert);

        NSString *sound = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"sound"];
        NSLog(@"Received Push Sound: %@", sound);
        AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

        NSString *badge = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"badge"];
        NSLog(@"Received Push Badge: %@", badge);
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[apsInfo objectForKey:@"badge"] integerValue];

        NSString *notifUrl = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"url"];
        NSLog(@"Received Push Url: %@", notifUrl);

        // app was already in the foreground
        if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive ) {

            UIAlertView *alertPush = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Message"
                                                           message: alert
                                                          delegate: self
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"View"
                                                 otherButtonTitles: @"Cancel", nil];

            [alertPush show];
            [alertPush release];
        }
        // app is inactive or in the background
        else {
            [self Redirect:notifUrl];
        }

    #endif
    }

    // what to do if user taps the viewbutton in push notification alert view
    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
        if(buttonIndex == 0) {

            NSLog(@"View Button has been tapped");
            // We need the url that has been passed by the push notification


        }
        else {
            // Do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: You code looks ok, so where are you having any difficulties? In the delegate methods for the `UIAlertView`? You will need to save the url some where and pick it up in the delegate method again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how do I save the url so I can pick it up again? That's the challenge. Hopefully you have the golden tip :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just define your variable `notifUrl` in .h file so that you can access this in other methods of your class as well. Then store url in that variable and use that in alertview delegate method.

```
//Add this in .h file
NSString *notifUrl;

//Add this in .m file

-(void)Redirect:(NSString*)url{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
}     

/**
     * Remote Notification Received while application was open.
     */
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    #if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR

        NSLog(@"remote notification: %@",[userInfo description]);
        NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];

        NSString *alert = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"alert"];
        NSLog(@"Received Push Alert: %@", alert);

        NSString *sound = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"sound"];
        NSLog(@"Received Push Sound: %@", sound);
        AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

        NSString *badge = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"badge"];
        NSLog(@"Received Push Badge: %@", badge);
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[apsInfo objectForKey:@"badge"] integerValue];

        //Define this variable in .h file so that you can access this in other methods as well
        notifUrl = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"url"];
        NSLog(@"Received Push Url: %@", notifUrl);
        [notifUrl retain];    // this is retain value of notifUrl so that you can use it later
        // app was already in the foreground
        if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive ) {

            UIAlertView *alertPush = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Message"
                                                           message: alert
                                                          delegate: self
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"View"
                                                 otherButtonTitles: @"Cancel", nil];

            [alertPush show];
            [alertPush release];
        }
        // app is inactive or in the background
        else {
            [self Redirect:notifUrl];
        }

    #endif
    }

    // what to do if user taps the viewbutton in push notification alert view
    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
        if(buttonIndex == 0) {

            NSLog(@"View Button has been tapped");
            NSLog(@"Received Push Url: %@", notifUrl);
           [self Redirect:notifUrl];
        }
        else {
            // Do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how do I store the url in this variable? It's 'dynamic', cause the url will be passed by the notification and will change every time.

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm still doing it old-school ;)

Comment: YES! I've managed. One correction. The NSString *notifUrl part needs to be added at the top of the .m file after @implementation. Then it is working. Thanks!